# bundle is locked to heroku (3.99.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, heroku-postgres

I typed `heroku create` in my rails project and then I add to the Gemfile the `gem 'pg'` then I typed bundle and this error showed up to me, any solutions to this problem?

`The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run`bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Your bundle is locked to heroku (3.99.3), but that version could not be found in
any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that
means the author of heroku (3.99.3) has removed it. You'll need to update your
bundle to a version other than heroku (3.99.3) that hasn't been removed in order
to install.`

Comment: You should be aware that the `heroku` gem has been deprecated for at least a year. Much of its functionality may be broken as APIs change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version `3.99.3` of the `heroku` gem was yanked. That means it is not available anymore. See the list of [versions on Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/heroku/versions).

Only version `3.99.4` is still available. Install it by running:

```
bundle update heroku
```

You might want to consider removing that gem because it is unsupported and use there new [`heroku CLI`](https://github.com/heroku/cli) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by using `bundle update`